# Regex on Python prints Garbage when use char class

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, utf-8

**Python 2.7**

I am processing a utf-8 encoded file (greek) and seems that `regex` has some issues.

`Regex` seems to work fine when i do not use char class. When i do :

```
        text = re.sub('αυ','kk',text,flags=re.UNICODE)
```

everything works fine and for instance 'αυτιά' will be converted to 'kkτιά'.

However, when i want to use char class like :

```
        text = re.sub('αυ[τ]','kk',text,flags=re.UNICODE)
```

garbage character is shown and 'αυτιά' is converted to 'kk�ia'. 
Is it an encoding issue or is something wrong with my `regex` ? Excuse me but i am pretty new to `regex` mindset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass unicode objects instead of strings:

```
>>> print re.sub('αυ[τ]', 'kk', 'αυτιά', flags=re.UNICODE)
kk▒ιά
>>> print re.sub(u'αυ[τ]', u'kk', u'αυτιά', flags=re.UNICODE)
kkιά
```